# Component toggle not toggling

Tags: block-editor

I'm trying to create a checkbox in inspector controls that will change font size, but it doesn't get checked when clicked

```
var CheckboxControl = wp.components.CheckboxControl       
el(FormToggle,{
  help: 'If checked the text will show with large font',
  checked: false,
  label: 'Show large font',
  onChange: function(state){
      props.setAttributes({ textSize: state })
  }
})
```

On the [wordpress documentation](https://wordpress.org/gutenberg/handbook/designers-developers/developers/components/checkbox-control/) the code seems different than mine and it can't apply to what I have. I see that there it's a piece of code that change it's state but I can't integrate it in my code:

```
onChange={ ( isChecked ) => { setState( { isChecked } ) } }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used this toggler to add a class to an element if checked. Maybe your goal is the same with a class for a larger font. I used it like this:

```
checked: !!textSize,
onChange: function(){
                textSize ? props.setAttributes({ textSize: '' }) : props.setAttributes({ textSize: ' big' })
                    }
```

So textSize controls the checked status and holds the classname, if checked. You can use the textSize string in other elements className: attributes.

Comment: Very helpful! I get `Uncaught ReferenceError: textSize is not defined` even though I declared `textSize` in the `attributes` like this 
`textSize: {
          type: 'string'
}`

Am I missing something?

Comment: You can add `default: ''` to the declaration (i did so), but to get it in the edit: function you should add `var textSize = props.attributes.textSize` (after function (props) {...).